# How to calculate the 64 bit virtual address of the start of the .text (code) section

Tags: windows, 64-bit, portable-executable

I'm trying to calculate the 64 bit virtual address for the **start** and consequently the **end** of the **code (.text)** section for **ntoskrnl.exe** in my 64 bit KMDF driver. I'm not certain if my calculations are correct so I welcome any corrections. The calculation for NTBase is determined elsewhere in my project. This 64 bit address has been verified to be correct by way of Windbg.

```
extern IMAGE_DOS_HEADER* NtBase; // base address of ntoskrnl.exe

PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER dosHeader;
PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS NtHeader;
PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER sectionHeader;
PIMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER64 pOptionalHeader;

UINT64 nNumberSections;
UINT64* pStartOfCode = 0;
UINT64* pEndOfCode = 0;

DbgPrintEx(DPFLTR_SYSTEM_ID, DPFLTR_ERROR_LEVEL, "NtBase is located at address 0x%p\n", NtBase); // NtBase from ntoskrnl.exe in memory
dosHeader = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)NtBase;

if (dosHeader->e_magic == IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE)
{
    PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS64 NtHeader = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)((UCHAR*)dosHeader + dosHeader->e_lfanew);
    if (NtHeader->Signature == IMAGE_NT_SIGNATURE)
    {
        sectionHeader = IMAGE_FIRST_SECTION(NtHeader);
        nNumberSections = NtHeader->FileHeader.NumberOfSections;

        sectionHeader = IMAGE_FIRST_SECTION(NtHeader);
        pOptionalHeader = (PIMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER64) & (NtHeader->OptionalHeader);

        for (UINT64 i = 0; i < nNumberSections; i++)
        {
            if (RtlCompareMemory(sectionHeader->Name, ".text", 6) == 6)
            {
                DbgPrintEx(DPFLTR_SYSTEM_ID, DPFLTR_ERROR_LEVEL, "%-8s\t%x\t%x\t%x\n", sectionHeader->Name, sectionHeader->VirtualAddress, sectionHeader->PointerToRawData, sectionHeader->SizeOfRawData);
                pStartOfCode = (UINT64*)NtBase + sectionHeader->VirtualAddress;
                pEndOfCode = pStartOfCode + (UINT64)pOptionalHeader->SizeOfCode;
                break;
            }
            sectionHeader++;
        }                   
    }
}
return STATUS_SUCCESS;
```

Comment: The field `SizeOfCode` is not meant to be used in this way. It specifies the total size of code data across the file. Instead of it, you have to use the `IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER::VirtualSize` field.

Comment: @jtxkopt can you provide a code snippet for arriving at this structure (IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER) ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a kernel mode API that allows safe access to ntoskrnl.exe address space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72036519/is-there-a-kernel-mode-api-that-allows-safe-access-to-ntoskrnl-exe-address-space)

Comment: All you need to do is to replace `(UINT64)pOptionalHeader->SizeOfCode` with `sectionHeader->Misc.VirtualSize`.

Comment: @jtxkopt thank you. I also need a comment on the original code above where I'm calculating the start of code of ntoskrnl.exe as follows: (UINT64* pStartOfCode = (UINT64*)NtBase + sectionHeader->VirtualAddress;) Is this correct ? If you post your comment as an answer I will accept.

Comment: Yes, it is correct and there is already no another way to get the start address of a section in an executable PE file. You add the offset to the base address and get the actual location of the section, that is it. Since StackOverflow is not a code review community, this cannot be an answer. Keep in mind that you should ask this kind of questions on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: As a note, the code data is not always in the `.text` section. It can be splitted into several sections. To decide if a section contains code, you should check the section characteristics, so `IMAGE_SCN_CNT_CODE`.

Comment: @RaymondChen I accepted the answer (which was mine) to that particular question/post.

Answer (score 0):

The start of the code portion is generally the start of the first element in the section array that is marked as containing code in its flags bits (called Characteristics in some structures).  End of code portion is generally the end of the last such element in the section array.  SizeOfCode in PE header should ideally be the difference between those two virtual addresses.

Note however that the start of the first code section is rarely the start of the actual code or even code at all, as most compilers put some read-only data before the first piece of code, such as a reference to the debug data file in PDB format or the table of imported DLL identifiers.  The actual first code to run is at the virtual address listed in the PE header as the program start address, that code is often a wrapper function provided by the language runtime and marked by being named in the END assembler directive in its own assembler source code or in an /ENTRY:name linker switch specified in the build settings and/or embedded in a ".directive" section in some .obj file [ The Microsoft linker defaults to looking for the name used by the Microsoft C runtime for DLL or EXE as specified ].

Modern systems typically ignore the SizeOfCode value, but historically it was intended to help the program loader to easily figure out how much address space to mark as executable, but in practice, the PE section array provides the appropriate per section page access flags.  Beware however that for kernel mode modules, outdated methods were used long after user mode had stopped assuming that each file had the typical section order.